# HTML download fails saying "Failed-No file" with python flask server

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, server, download

I am new to the world of web programming, and wanted to see if I could create a download for a zip file. I created an anchor element in my HTML like this: `<a href="./download/myFile.zip" download>Download File</a>` Then, I created my Flask server like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="C:/Users/User/Desktop/website")
@app.route('/')
def upload_file():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I then started the server and went to the address. I clicked on Download File, and it said Failed- No file. My website directory looks like that.
[image]

The only file inside of the folder download is myFile.zip. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? If you want to see the full code in index.html, it's below. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File</h1>
    
    <h2>Download</h2>
    <a href="./download/myFile.zip" download>Download File</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post all your code here ?

Comment: @Frank AK I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is serving the `download` folder.

A quick workaround might be to set the static folder to `download` specifically:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="C:/Users/User/Desktop/website"
                      static_folder="download")
```

However you may wish to stick with the default which is `'static'` (instead of providing that `static_folder` argument.

So instead you could rename your `download` folder to `static` and generate the link with Jinja2 syntax which would be:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='myFile.zip') }}" download>Download File</a>
```

This URL then renders as:

```
/static/myFile.zip
```

If you wanted to go further, and store the downloadable files in a folder called `static/download` the Jinja Syntax would be:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='download/myFile.zip') }}
```